# Client-Server chatting in Lua

Tags: networking, tcp, lua

Server Program

```
local socket = require("socket")
local server = socket.try(socket.bind("*", 1234))
local ip, port = server:getsockname()
while 1 do
    local client = server:accept()
    client:settimeout(10)
    local line, err = client:receive()
    print (line)
    print("Enter input:")
    if not err then client:send(io.read().."\n")  end
    client:close()
end
```

Client Program

```
local host, port = "*", 1234
local socket = require("socket")
local tcp = assert(socket.tcp())
tcp:connect(host, port);
tcp:send("Connection Established\n");
while 1 do
    local s, status, partial = tcp:receive()
    print(s or partial)
    print("Enter input:")
    tcp:send(io.read().."\n");
    if status == "closed" then break end 
end
tcp:close()
```

The server program can send the message to client but the client can't send message to server. Is there any way to do it..??

Comment: `tcp:connect(host, port);` requires the `host` to not be `*`.

Comment: may be you do not send data in 10 second after connection?

Comment: Can you eloborate more on what exactly is happening? I see server can send anything only on receving some data from server?

Comment: **The client first send a message as "connection established" Then the server can send a message to client. After that no more message transfer occurs. Is  there any way for client and server to chat continuously?**

Comment: **I have changed the timeout to 1000 but still its not working.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have enough reputation to comment, but after 10 seconds or the server sending a message, whichever comes first, the server closes the connection. The client doesn't attempt to send a message until after the server has sent a message, and the way you've written your code the server immediately closes the connection at this point. If you want the two to communicate you'd be better off accepting the client outside of the loop like so:

Server Program

```
local socket = require("socket")
local server = socket.try(socket.bind("*", 1234))
local ip, port = server:getsockname()
local client = server:accept()
client:settimeout(10)
while 1 do
    local line, err = client:receive()
    print (line)
    print("Enter input:")
    if not err then client:send(io.read().."\n")  end
end
client:close()
```

Now, this brings up the issue in which the server lacks the code to realize a client has disconnected and needs to find a new client, however it shouldn't be that difficult to implement.

Comment: **Thanks its working but the client's message to server  is displayed only after server has sent something to client ie., the order of chatting is not correct**